# Issue with PropertyInfo getProperty() Method

Tags: c#, api, properties, mapping, propertyinfo

```
request.Data
{
    "jurisdictionCode": "California",
    "claimId": 123654,
    "claimGroupID": 12,
    "claimXref": "32145",
    "serviceXref": "Test",
    "claimStart": "2021-07-30T13:20:15.338Z",
    "claimEnd": "2021-07-30T13:20:15.338Z",
    "status": 5,
    "creationTimestamp": "2021-07-30T13:20:15.338Z",
    "touchTimestamp": "2021-07-30T13:20:15.338Z",
    "filingSource": 7,
    "userName": "test",
    "exportTs": "2021-07-30T13:20:15.338Z",
    "payerXref": "test",
    "dtbatchExportTs": "2021-07-30T13:20:15.338Z"
  }


public class scaffolded_model
{
[Key]
[StringLength(10)]
public string JurisdictionCode { get; set; }

[Key]
public long ClaimID { get; set; }   

public long ClaimGroupID { get; set; }  

[Required]
[StringLength(64)]
public string ClaimXRef { get; set; }   

[Required]
[StringLength(64)]
public string ServiceXRef { get; set; } 

[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime ClaimStart { get; set; }    

[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime ClaimEnd { get; set; }

public int Status { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime CreationTimestamp { get; set; } 

[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime TouchTimestamp { get; set; }

public int FilingSource { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(256)]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime ExportTS { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(64)]
public string PayerXRef { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime DTBatchExportTS { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
    var data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request.Data);

Dictionary<string, JsonElement> result = (Dictionary<string, JsonElement>)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(data, typeof(Dictionary<string, JsonElement>));

foreach (var item in result)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = scaffolded_model
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty(item.Key, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
   
    if (pi == null)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Bad Field");
        continue;
    }
    pi.SetValue(scaffolded_model, item.Value);
}
```

I have been having issues with using the GetProperty() method to match and populate values from a json request coming in as request.Data and an Empty model called scaffolded_model. As far as I can tell, both sets of data are setup correctly. The code should run through each value in the request, match it by item.key in the empty model and populate the matching key with the value. item.key comes up empty everytime. I have tried different bindings, etc. If I hard code the first item.key coming through as JurisdictionCode, it grabs the value and populates it correctly. So everything is working, if the item.key would populate.

Thanks for looking and for all of your help.

```
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [HttpPost("v{version:apiVersion}/Submitclaim")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public Task<IActionResult> Submitclaim(ClaimModel request)
    {
        var source = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        IActionResult actionResult = null;
        
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("jx", request.JurisdictionCode))
        {
            try 
            {
                //var claim_data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
                //Dictionary<string, JsonElement> result = (Dictionary<string, JsonElement>)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(claim_data, typeof(Dictionary<string, JsonElement>));

                API.CRUD.Claims.Model.Claim scaffolded_model = new API.CRUD.Claims.Model.Claim();

                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<scaffolded_model>(request);

                //foreach (var item in result)
                //{
                //    PropertyInfo pi = scaffolded_model
                //      .GetType()
                //      .GetProperty(
                //         item.Key,
                //         BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

                //    if (pi == null)
                //    {
                //        _logger.LogInformation("Bad Field");
                //        continue;
                //    }
                //    pi.SetValue(
                //      scaffolded_model,
                //      Convert.ChangeType(item.Value.ToString(), pi.PropertyType));
                //}


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Exception failed: {ex.Message}");
                actionResult = Problem("Exception failed");
            }

        }

        return Task.FromResult(actionResult);

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand: why don't you just deserialize directly into your `scaffolded_model` type, you shouldn't be writing the deserialization yourself: `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<scaffolded_model>(data)`. I note that it's obviously pointless to serialize then immediately deserialize JSON, perhaps you are just testing. If so, the JSON you provide at the top is clearly not matching, as that has the outer root object also.

Comment: Do you have *different* JSON that you are receiving, or is the JSON at the the top really the one you want to deserialize? Further, your code is anyway broken: `item.Value.ToString()` should be just `item.Value`

Comment: Hi CharlieFace, I cleaned up the request like you had pointed out. Also, I would love to deserialize directly into my Modal if possible. I'm not quite sure how to do that though. Using the suggestions below from Botan, I can now pass strings, and would need to handle Datetime and null values, which I have no idea how to do..

Comment: Sorry still not getting it: why can't you just deserialize as I showed: `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<scaffolded_model>(data)`

Comment: Hi CharlieFace, Sorry for the confusion, Basically, this is an API call, which I will give you all of the code for. When I try and take the request coming in, which is the request.Data and I try to Deserialize directly to the newly created model, I get a few errors. Not sure what is wrong:

Comment: I'll add it up top:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a good reason to implement custom JSON parsing via Reflection instead of using standard System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json libraries, then there are couple issues that need to be resolved:

- Type.GetProperty is case sensitive. By default it will not match `jurisdictionCode` property name to `JurisdictionCode` property. The [`BindingFlags.IgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=net-5.0) flag should solve this issue.

```
PropertyInfo pi = scaffolded_model
  .GetType()
  .GetProperty(
     item.Key, 
     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
```

- The second issue is related to the type conversion. [`PropertyInfo.SetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=net-5.0) does not perform any type conversions. The value that need to be set must match property type, otherwise `TargetException` will be thrown. At this time the code from the question always sets string value returned by `item.Value.ToString()` method to all properties. It will not work for `long` or `DateTime` properties. To resolve this issue, the [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-5.0) method can be used as the simplest option that will handle property types defined in the `scaffolded_model` class.

```
pi.SetValue(
  scaffolded_model, 
  Convert.ChangeType(item.Value.ToString(), pi.PropertyType));
```

With these two changes it will be possible to parse Json form example.

---

But current code has some limitations:

- It does not handle nulls. In case of string property, the empty string value will be assigned to the property instead of original null value. The nullable value types (e.g. long?) are not supported at all. To resolve this issue, current logic can be adjusted to check the `JsonElement.ValueKind` property for `JsonValueKind.Null` value.
- Another issue is a `DateTime` type. With the current implementation all `DateTime` values will be adjusted to the local timezone, and `Convert.ChangeType` method does not provide any ability to control it. The replacement of `DateTime` time to `DateTimeOffset` will not work as `Convert.ChangeType` method does not support it. There is only option to check property type and perform manual conversion using, for example, `DateTime.Parse` method instead of `Convert.ChangeType`.

This list can be continued. So in general case it is better to use standard libraries for parsing Json.

Comment: Hi Botan, Thanks for the help. We had to remove NewtonSoft from our project due to conflicting issues and we are using a scaffolded model library in a different project that is making this more difficult. As far as the issues with the Nulls and DateTime, I understand what you are saying, could you elaborate more on how I could modify my code to handle both of the issues?  Also, the item.Value.ToString() addition in my code was just me testing things and doesn't need to be there unless it has to. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: Hi @user1615351, I see that you have updated the question and included the actual code of the controller action.
Now it has become clearer what you are going to achieve.
I highly recommend to avoid Reflection in this situation, it will create more problems rather than solve anything.
The simplest and most reliable solution will be manually populate properties of scaffolded_model based on the original request.
The trick with deserialization will work only if names and types  properties of scaffolded_model completely match properties of original request by name and by type.

Comment: Hi @user1615351, could you please try to deserialize scaffolded_model using the following statement:
`API.CRUD.Claims.Model.Claim scaffolded_model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<API.CRUD.Claims.Model.Claim>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });`
Where the jsonString is an actual JSON that need to be deserialized into scaffolded_model.
According to your example, property names in the model and in the example JSON differ in case.
The `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` option set to true will allow case-insensitive property matching.

Comment: Thank you for your info Botan. My code is working now.